# Close and delete button spacings are off

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

The close and delete buttons appear to be padded with more space than the other buttons (share, edit, flag, protect). This is probably due to the new "close (1/5)" text that started appearing today.

Example:

[image]

I'm using Firefox 19 on a Mac.

Comment: This is correct. It says "Close (1/5) to represent how many votes left are needed to pass the action (or how many votes there are currently, I forget)

Comment: Yes, but when there are no close/delete votes, it is spaced incorrectly.

Comment: Yep it looks... weird.

Comment: It's on Arqade too, and I don't even have 3k.

Comment: Probably because of (1/5) feature they included.

Comment: I can confirm. I am on Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m in Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Hi Kevin, this was flagged as not an answer. I suggest that you stop fixing bugs so you can focus on answering the question. To learn more, see our [tips on writing great answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yep, it's now fixed on [so] and [metase]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a fault of the HTML itself, rather than the CSS.

```html
<a id="close-question-15421502" title="vote to close this question (when closed, no new answers can be added)">
        close
</a>
```

Because of the extra lines within the anchor tag, it collapses them as spaces. The styling on the link is exactly the same as the other links otherwise.
Removing these extra lines fixes the problem.

Comment: This does appear to be the cause, but I can't figure out *why*. They must have some non-breaking spaces in there somewhere, because *normal* spaces would be completely stripped from the beginning and end of text within an element like that. [Like seen here.](http://jsfiddle.net/r8qS7/)

Comment: Hm, you seem to be right... Can't find any `whitespace` declarations in the CSS that might circumvent that, and I can't reproduce it in JSfiddle either...

Comment: @animuson: Actually, in HTML, multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space. Then leading/trailing spaces are stripped. See http://jsfiddle.net/r8qS7/1/. So, Nightfirecat is correct -- the extra whitespace results in the errant spacing. (Now that we know the cause, here's to hoping it gets fixed!)

Comment: @nneonneo: Ah right, it only does that if there's other inline content around it. I've never noticed because I never do that. - Also, it's actually *CSS* that collapses white-space, not HTML. ;) There's absolutely nothing in the HTML specs about collapsing white-space; it's just a markup language.

Comment: @animuson: Before the advent of CSS, this was definitely specified in HTML, as early as [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#sgml). [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) makes a mention as well. It may or may not have to do with its roots in SGML, as only in HTML5 is this behavior no longer mentioned in the HTML spec (as HTML5 isn't SGML-based but a language in its own right).

Comment: @animuson: Even [CSS1's description of `white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#white-space) simply linked to the HTML 4 spec! Of course, that's all legacy; [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop) outlines it in much greater detail now, and modern browsers make extensive (if not exclusive) use of CSS to render pages.