# "close (x/5)" spacing off

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

> *Related:* [Close and delete button spacings are off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171956/close-and-delete-button-spacings-are-off) (fixed)

A trailing space appears after the text "Close (x/5)". The space only appears when there's at least one close vote. Example:

> [image]

Note the space after the (3/5). I don't believe this appeared 20 minutes ago, which makes me think that the bug was introduced in the most recent deployed build.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a id="close-question-nnnnnnn" title="2 more votes are needed to close this question" class="load-tooltip-on-hover">close                (3/5)
</a>
```

The odd spacing is the result of the trailing newline.

Comment: How do you notice these things...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close and delete button spacings are off](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171956/close-and-delete-button-spacings-are-off)

Comment: hmmm, maybe I should have just put that up as related, since they said they had fixed it.  You're probably right about an error in the last deploy.

Comment: I *did* put that up as related :P

Comment: Guess I scanned too fast, [wish I could remove my close vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.