# Where did "close (x/5)" go?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

As much as I [loved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171956/close-and-delete-button-spacings-are-off) [complaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172590/close-x-5-spacing-off) about the "close (x/5)" feature (showing the total number of votes needed), I kind of liked that feature. Plus, as I recall, the number of delete votes needed to delete a post is not necessarily a constant, so it's nice to know how many votes are needed at a glance.

Where did the feature go? Why was it nixed? (Was it because I complained too much about it? Because I promise not to do that in the future if that's the case ;) )

Comment: I have been wondering that as well, it has disappeared!

Comment: I don't have 3K on SO, but on MSO, it still shows a variation... I'm seeing `close(x)` without the `/5`

Comment: @psubsee2003: that's the way it's always been, but for a brief period recently, it showed something more like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/823BZ.png

Comment: @nneonneo thanks.... I only hit 3K on MSO recently, so I only briefly saw the  `close (x/5)`, I wasn't aware this was the standard prior to that, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It's visible on hover I believe, or I'm sure it said that in the changelog

Comment: @animuson: While the answer is there, the question is rather different.

Comment: @nneonneo: That doesn't matter anymore. All that matters is *the answer is there*. A different question that has the same answer serves as a signpost to the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Jarrod's answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173909/169611

They got rid of it because it was causing too many layout issues.

Answer (score 4):

We removed it because it was messing up the layout on many sites while not really providing a big benefit.

Basically, we (and users, far as we could tell) didn't love the feature enough to fix the issues it caused instead of just taking it back out.